# Non-functioning internal microphone - device not listed

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a HP Elitebook 850 G6. Recently, for an unknown reason but perhaps an update, the sound card stopped working.

For a broader context of what happened: all internal audio devices were not listed in both the sound settings page as well `pavucontrol`. I was able to restore audio output following the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/1509312/sound-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-linux-5-4-intel-hd-audio/1509313#1509313

However, despite hours of trying to find solutions, I still cannot get my laptop's internal microphone to work. Currently, it is still not showing up in the sound setting device list, and in the Pulse Audio control panel, the entry for "Built-in Audio Stereo" has "Microphone (unplugged)" listed as the "Port".

The microphone disable key (fn+f7) has an amber light on, but trying to toggle it has no effect on anything.

Running `arecord -l` gives this response:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC215 Analog [ALC215 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB PnP Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I then tried record from the HDA Intel PCH device with this command `arecord -f S16_LE -c 2 -D hw:0,0 -d 5 -r 192000 test.wav` however it produced a silent file.

Running 'alsamixer` followed by 'f5' gives this:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.1.3 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                                                                              F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Realtek ALC215                                                                                             F2:  System information │
│ View: F3: Playback  F4: Capture  F5:[All]                                                                        F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -21.00]                                                                                   Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                                                                                          │
│      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐                                                        ┌──┐                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │  │      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │  │                  │
│      │▒▒│      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │▒▒│                  │
│      │▒▒│      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │▒▒│                  │
│      │▒▒│      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │▒▒│                  │
│      │▒▒│      │  │      │▒▒│      │▒▒│      │  │      │  │                                                        │▒▒│                  │
│      ├──┤      ├──┤      ├──┤      └──┘      └──┘      └──┘      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      ┌──┐      └──┘     Enabled      │
│      │OO│      │MM│      │OO│                                    │MM│      │OO│      │OO│      │OO│      │OO│                            │
│      └──┘      └──┘      └──┘                                    └──┘      └──┘      └──┘      └──┘      └──┘     L    R                 │
│                                                                                                                  CAPTURE                 │
│       40       0<>0    100<>100  100<>100    0<>0      0<>0                                                       39<>39                 │
│   < Master  >Headphone  Speaker     PCM    Mic Boost Mic Boost  S/PDIF   S/PDIF 1  S/PDIF 2  S/PDIF 3  S/PDIF 4   Capture  Auto-Mute     │
│                                                                                                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I have already wasted about 4 hours work time trying to get my microphone working again, and it is imperative that I *do* in fact get it working again because this is a work machine and I am expected to attend and participate in online meetings due to the ncov-19 outbreak. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.